# Why object file size changes for the same code in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I have written same lines of code in both C and C++ build environment of visual studio 2008 but C code's object file size is 5.5kb and C++ code file size is 6.17 kb. Why is this difference?

Following is the code in both environments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S
{
    char c;
};
void func()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("%d", i);
}

int main()
{
    struct S s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, different languages do tend to be different. That's what "different" means. ;)

Comment: It's bigger, because bigger is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It links different C runtime libraries in each case. [Check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for detailed explanation. For instance, `libcmt.lib` vs `libcpmt.lib`.

Comment: Why so? Because the code is same, same parts should be linked, as far as I think.

Comment: Because C and C++ are different programming languages.

Comment: @Vikas: In C++ you need to have, for example, the code to handle exception or C++ specific allocation ("new", "delete"). You can try to disable exception handling in your C++ project and it should lower the file size.

Answer (score 4):

Just because your code has different meaning in C and C++.

- In C++ you declare functions that
  receive no arguments, in C you
  declare functions that have an
  unspecified number of arguments. (*Never* change the signature of `main`)
- function names are mangled in C++
- functions may throw exceptions in C++
- executables are linked against
  different libraries by default
- because of the lack of initialization
  of `i` the call to `printf` has
  undefined behavior. Both languages
  might decide on different strategies
  to shoot you.

Comment: Although all these things are true, the only salient point is the set of libraries which are linked in.

Comment: @Adam: not sure, he is talking about the object files not the executable files. At as far as I can see on my machine the difference is in the size of the symbol table. For me the C version has exactly the three external symbols that are mentioned, for C++ there are more.

Answer (score -4):

The include file `stdio.h` has a <s>much</s> more complicated compilation for C++<s>as it probably derives the stdio functions on top of the iostreams functions.  For a straight C compile, iostream isn't used</s>.  So the object file is smaller in C.

---

**edit**

I don't think many of the downvoters understand the question.  OP is asking why the *object file* has increased in size.  Not the executable.  Not the library.

After looking at stdio.h for VS 2008, I see that the compilation differences for `C++` and `C` are not nearly as dramatic as they are for `gcc`, which was the basis of my original answer.  Still, the namespacing and mangled external symbols make the object file bigger.

Comment: I hope this wasn't an interview question for you.